# Getting User Information with Add-In-Only-Authentication

Tags: 2013, user-profile, authentication, provider-hosted-app, sharepoint-addin

I need to write a SharePoint Add-In (provider-hosted, CSOM) that has the permission to write entries in the hosts' SharePoint-List even if the user has no permission to do that.

That's why I want to use Add-In-Only-Authentication.

But I also need to know something about the user like his Groups to provide some permission-specific content on my own.

IMHO you lose any info from the user when Add-In-Only-authentication is used. Is there a way to get the best from both worlds? Can I mix both authentication-types without the user having to accept OAuth-permissions twice?